# Suspended user can still post?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, account-suspension

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691390/catherine) has been suspended until May 11, and that already for quite a while. She made a second account, called sally, and eventually got found out. So as far as I could tell, her accounts were merged.

And now, although she's suspended, she can post again? : [Convert and save distance matrix to a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813156/r-how-to-convert-and-save-distance-matrix-to-a-specific-format)

Not that I mind, I just wondered if that was a bug of some kind, or intentional. Given the quality of her questions, can't really believe she hacked herself an entrance...

Comment: Interesting, I don't know when he/she got suspended though.

Comment: @YOU : definitely not yesterday, that must have been two weeks ago or so.

Comment: Maybe the suspension works only for Registered accounts? Noticed her account is unregistered..

Comment: @ShadowWizard : How comes then that I click on the account link, and I arrive at the suspended account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doubtful. I suspect she posted as a new user then was merged into the current suspended user.

Comment: @Jeff : that's exactly what I said, no? ;) Plus, the merging was done before that last question was asked, because I saw that happen yesterday. Her new question is only 5 hours old.

Comment: @Joris, Jeff probably means: posted as *yet another* new user. A 3rd account (or 4th, ...) that meanwhile has been merged into the suspended account as well. (If true, then maybe the question should have been deleted rather than rewarding the user by merging the question into the suspended account?)

Comment: @Arjan : ah thx, I misunderstood.

Comment: But in previous case the extra account has been deleted with all its questions, not merged.. ? (hint: backstabber)

Comment: Merged another two accounts.  Maybe this one should be put in the ban bin.

Comment: And another one just now. If I see any more posts by this user, I'm going to be deleting instead of merging. @Will